# colspan rowspan issue?

Tags: html, html-table

Im trying to create a table which has 6 columns and 6 rows.
the first td should be spread across four columns and four rows.
then the second td of the first row should be 2 col span.
the bottom two rows are just 6 tds.

this is the code im trying...
http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/dByer/1/

but its messing up...this is what im trying to get...

[image]

Comment: Your picture has four rows, not six. Where's the typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use rowspan over rows that does not exist.
And you bottom rows did not have enough columns.

Try this:

```
<table id="phototable" border=1>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="4">1</td> 
  <td colspan="2">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td> 
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td> 
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you want, with 'placeholder' cells added to achieve the desired layout: http://jsfiddle.net/NGP3x/

You are stretching rowspans over rows that aren't there though... you might just want to use CSS to get the visual result you have in mind.

[image]